# How can I Implement Win/loss statistics in Rock Paper Scissors Game?

Tags: python

> I want to display the current statistics of the game after every match

```
import random

while True:
    user_action = input("Enter a choice: (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    comp_action = random.choice(possible_actions)
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    ties = 0




    print(f"\nYou chose {user_action}, computer chose {comp_action}.\n")

    if user_action == comp_action:
        print(f"Both players selected {user_action}. It's a tie!")
        ties +=1
    elif user_action == "rock":
        if comp_action == "scissors":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
            wins += 1
        else:
             print("Paper beats Rock. You lose! ")
             losses +=1
    elif user_action == "paper":
        if comp_action == "rock":
            print("Paper beats rock. You win!")
            wins += 1
        else:
            print("Scissors beats paper! You lose.")
            losses += 1
    elif user_action == "scissors":
        if comp_action == "paper":
            print("Scissors beats paper! You win!")
            wins += 1
        else:
            print("Rock beats scissors! You lose.")
            losses +=1
    print(f"won {wins / sum((wins, losses, ties))}%, {ties} ties")


    again = input("Want to play again? (y/n): ")
    if again.lower() != "y":
        break
```

> I want to show the computer's wins, the user's wins, and the amount of ties along with their win/loss percentages.
>
> Player wins: 0 (0.0%)
>
> Computer wins: 1 (100.0%)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make 3 counters for the game endings:

`wins = losses = ties = 0`

and increase them every time it happens like so:

```
print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
wins += 1
```

at the end print them:

```
print(f"won {wins / sum((wins, losses, ties))}%, {ties} ties")
```

Comment: when I implement the last printing function, I get "TypeError: sum() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)" is there something I need to remove?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put them in a tuple. now fixed.

Comment: I had to add an extra closed parenthesis  after "ties", but thank you.

Comment: oops I meant after 'sum((wins, losses, ties' instead of two it should have been 3 closed parenthesis.

Comment: still thank you. all the brackets should be correct now.

Comment: okay so after playing with it, I have noticed that whenever I get a tie, it doesn't increase. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: For me the the ties variable increases. Do you want the percentage to increase?

Comment: I was able to find what I was doing wrong. I fixed it now. Thank you for all the help.